# How get img src in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am beginner in js / jQuery.

I have this code:

```
var imageArray = [];
    $(document).on("click", ".showPrv", function () {
        $("#dropzone").each(function () {
            $(".dz-image-preview").each(function () {
                $(".dz-image").each(function () {
                    console.log($(this));
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

this return me:

```
[Log] k (1) (1, line 734)
0 
<div class="dz-image">
<img data-dz-thumbnail alt="11" src="http://pscms2.test/upload/DZ_TEXT_PAGE/d3320b13a0f9c35bcdc98534b3aba06f.jpeg">
</div>

Prototyp k

[Log] k (1) (1, line 734)
0 
<div class="dz-image">
<img data-dz-thumbnail alt="12" src="http://pscms2.test/upload/DZ_TEXT_PAGE/3c5ed6a66822be7ea490b9e446de1451.jpeg">
</div>

Prototyp k

[Log] k [<div class="dz-image">] (1) (1, line 734)
[Log] k [<div class="dz-image">] (1) (1, line 734)
[Log] k [<div class="dz-image">] (1) (1, line 734)
[Log] k [<div class="dz-image">] (1) (1, line 734)
[Log] k [<div class="dz-image">] (1) (1, line 734)
[Log] k [<div class="dz-image">] (1) (1, line 734)
[Log] k [<div class="dz-image">] (1) (1, line 734)
```

I need to add src content to the imageArray array. The array must have unique src values (no duplicates). How can I do this?

The effect I want to achieve:

```
imageArray = ['http: //pscms2.test/upload/DZ_TEXT_PAGE/d3320b13a0f9c35bcdc98534b3aba06f.jpeg', 'http: //pscms2.test/upload/DZ_TEXT_PAGE/3c5ed6a66822be7ea490519.j4']
```

Please help me

Comment: HTML belong to XML famliy languages, scr is an attribute

Comment: Your html code is not supposed to have multiple element with same `id`. Do you really have multiple element with `dropZone` `id` ? and multiple `dz-image-preview` in `dropZone` elements ? Please provide entire `dropZone` html code.

Comment: attach your html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the `img` element from the selected element, you can use `.find()`, then use `.attr('src')` to get the src attribute value and push to the array with `arr.push()`

Try this

```js
var imageArray = [];
    $(document).on("click", ".showPrv", function () {
        $("#dropzone").each(function () {
            $(".dz-image-preview").each(function () {
                $(".dz-image").each(function () {
                  const src = $(this).find("img").attr("src")
                  if(imageArray.indexOf(src) < 0)
                    imageArray.push(src)
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. I make this code: var imageArray = [];
    $(document).on("click", ".showPrv", function () {
        $("#dropzone").each(function () {
            $(".dz-image-preview").each(function () {
                $(".dz-image").each(function () {
                    imageArray.push($(this).find("img").attr("src"))
                });
            });
        });
        console.log(imageArray);
    }) - in result I have:

Comment: ["http://pscms2.test/upload/DZ_TEXT_PAGE/d3320b13a0f9c35bcdc98534b3aba06f.jpeg", "http://pscms2.test/upload/DZ_TEXT_PAGE/3c5ed6a66822be7ea490b9e446de1451.jpeg", "http://pscms2.test/upload/DZ_TEXT_PAGE/87dd197957c0e3720f59f049235d093a.jpeg", "http://pscms2.test/upload/DZ_TEXT_PAGE/d3320b13a0f9c35bcdc98534b3aba06f.jpeg", "http://pscms2.test/upload/DZ_TEXT_PAGE/3c5ed6a66822be7ea490b9e446de1451.jpeg", "http://pscms2.test/upload/DZ_TEXT_PAGE/87dd197957c0e3720f59f049235d093a.jpeg", "http://pscms2.test/upload/DZ_TEXT_PAGE/d3320b13a0f9c35bcdc98534b3aba06f.jpeg] (9) - i have duplicate

Comment: you want only the two images ??

Comment: Yes. I need array without duplicates :)